# Netcat connection not working both ways (Mac-Kali), connection refused

Tags: networking, mac, kali-linux, netcat

I was following [this website](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nc-command) in order to establish a netcat connection. I have a mac and a kali virtual machine. If from my mac I type `nc -lv 1234` and from kali I type `nc ip.of.my.mac 1234` then the netcat connection is established. However, if I do the reverse, i.e. on my kali I type `nc -lv 1234` and on my mac I type `ip.of.my.kali 1234` then I get `nc: connectx to ip.of.my.kali port 1234 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`. Could you help me to debug the issue?

Comment: Disable the firewalls and try again.

Comment: @harrymc, it seems mac's firewall is disabled by default